# Shrink Frequent Used Method in c#

Tags: c#

I created a WindowsFormsApplication and my code contains many methods which start with:

```
chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points. ...
```

That's why I'm asking if there is a way to shrink this part to just one Word,
So I could just type

```
chartPoints.Clear();
```

**Please tell me if this is possible or not.**

By the way here is a little part of my code:

```
chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points.Clear();
chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points.Add(point1);
chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points.FindByValue(point1).LegendText = "point1";
chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points.AddY(point2);
```

Comment: you can store it in a variable then make your calls on it like; var points=chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points; points.Clear(); etc...

Comment: Your question is fine, though your "This is my first question..." comment should be a comment on the question.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That concept is called variables ;-)

```
var chartPoints = chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points;
chartPoints.Clear();
chartPoints.Add(point1);
// ...
```

Note that [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) is just a placeholder of the actual type, you don't have to use it. I have used it because i didn't know the real type.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a little helper method for that (please replace `POINTS_TYPE` with the actual type of `Points`):

```
public POINTS_TYPE GetPoints(string chartName)
{
    return chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points;
}
```

and then you can use

```
GetPoints(chartName).Clear();
```

I assumed that `chartName` is not always the same and your are using the value of `Points` in several places and thus needs to be included and you can't simply store `chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points` in a helper-variable. If you just use it in one method a few times Tim's solution is easier/better.

Answer (score 0):

Say:

```
var chartObj = chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points;

chartObj.Clear();
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just wrap `chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName)` inside a method in your form. I don't know what type does this return so for the same of example I'm just going to return `SomeType`:

```
SomeType chartPoints()
{
    return chart1.Series.FindByName(chartName).Points;
}
```

However, you can do better then that. You can pass the chartName to your method:

```
SomeType chartPoints(string name)
{
    return chart1.Series.FindByName(name).Points;
}
```